# Multiple nested array from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using foreach loops to access records in a nested array:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
    $test_groups[$row['group_name']][] = $row['lab_test'];
  }

  foreach($test_groups as $group_name => $tests){
    echo "<tr><td><span class='test_group_name'>" . $group_name . "</span></td></tr>";
    foreach($tests as $test){
        echo "<tr><td>" . $test . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

This works OK.  Now I need to add another level to the nested array, like:

```
$departments[$row['department_name']][$row['group_name']][] = $row['lab_test'];
```

Would this work and how should I adjust the for each loops above to cater for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign to array should be with `[]` at the end

```
$departments[$row['department_name']][$row['group_name']][] = $row['lab_test'];
```

Foreach loop will be:

```
foreach ($departments as $dep_name => $groups) {
    echo $dep_name;

    foreach ($groups as $group_name => $tests) {
        echo $group_name;

        foreach ($tests as $test) {
            echo $test;
        }
    }  
}
```

It's just with `echo`es, make there HTML as you need.